# Debug Odoo with Docker-compose in VS Code

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, docker-compose, odoo

I have a docker-compose file that runs Odoo14 fronted by Nginx. I would like to debug my Odoo plugins with Debudpy in VS code using this docker-compose configuration. I managed to get Debugpy installed in Docker using a "command" entry in the Odoo service docker-compose configuration.

Unfortunately, I cannot manage to get Odoo to run "wrapped" by Debugpy. I tried to override the entrypoint of the Odoo service to run debugpy and then the original entrypoint.sh like so:

entrypoint: python3 -m debugpy --listen 0.0.0.0:8888 entrypoint.sh

but this did not work.

Any idea how I could have a docker-compose file that runs Odoo & nginx and debug in VS code?
Help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: still looking for an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone needs it, the answer was actually quite simple. Instead of overriding the entrypoint file with mine, I just added the full command in my docker-compose file:

entrypoint: python3 -m debugpy --listen 0.0.0.0:8888 usr/bin/odoo -c /etc/odoo.conf

and it was enough to launch debugpy and odoo.